# I am passing both value and onChange to a controlled input element, why am I getting a Failed Prop Type error?

Tags: reactjs

Exactly as the title states, here is my input field, and I have verified that data is being passed down properly (the correct behavior works in the app as well), however I keep getting this error at runtime.

[image: React runtime error]

As you can see I am setting both props on the input, is this a bug or am I missing something?

P.S. Using the debugger, you can see `this.props.handleChange` and `this.props.name` are both defined values (like I said previously the correct behavior works).

```
<input
    type="text"
    onChange={this.props.handleChange}
    value={this.props.name}
    placeholder="Enter a unique name"
    />
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I needed to define the PropTypes, it's always the simple things staring you right in the face.

Before:

```
FlowNameInput.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

After:

```
FlowNameInput.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  errors: PropTypes.array,
  handleChange: PropTypes.func
};
```

Comment: can you post your complete component?

Comment: The code which you have shared is correct but that isn’t enough to diagnose the issue. You need to share complete component code to understand more about the issue

Comment: Please paste your code where props being passed to that component, to make sure you passing a valid props which can change value of the input

Answer (score 0):

Total rube mistake. Even though the props were being passed properly, they weren't defined in FlowNameInput's prop definitions.